# Does the AOT Setting Propagate to Dependent Class Libraries?

Tags: c#, compilation, blazor, .net-8.0, aot

We are using AOT in our Blazor WebAssembly project, in the csproj of main project we enable it like this:

```xml
<RunAOTCompilation Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    true
</RunAOTCompilation>
```

Our main project has several Razor Class Libraries as dependencies, my question is: does the AOT also "propagates" to those dependencies projects because the main project has AOT enabled? That is, does the whole project including all dependencies get AOT enabled because the main project has it enabled or should we enable AOT for every Razor Class Library independently (in their csproj) as well?